# Scrape YouTube Channel ID in to Google Sheets?

Tags: xml, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to scrape YouTube channel ID's (e.g. UCqwbZ-xTkn_EmyIhSvZRRWQ) and import it into Google Sheets using an IMPORTXML formula but getting no luck.
The channel ID can be found in the page source of a channel (https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCqwbZ-xTkn_EmyIhSvZRRWQ)

Can anyone give some guidance please on how to go about this?

In the Google sheet, I have a list of YouTube channel URL's and wanted to scrape these ID's.

I have managed it with scraping the subscribers, just no luck with the channel ID's.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

in your case, you don't need to scrape it from YouTube. try:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A2, "channel/(.+)")
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Not all links are in the same format...where they contain the channel ID... The first method is best.

Comment: In terms of scraping the channel name and number of subscriber? Do you know how we can go about doing that?

Comment: Thanks. It shows script for number of subscribers but not to pull the name of the channel. How can I adapt the script to pull the channel name?

Comment: try: `=INDEX(IMPORTHTML("https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC7_gcs09iThXybpVgjHZ_7g","list",1),1,1)`

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(QUERY(SUBSTITUTE(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(
 IMPORTDATA(A40), 3000, 1), """", ""),
 "where Col1 contains '<meta itemprop=channelId content='"),
 "<meta itemprop=channelId content=|>", ""))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: When I input the formula, it puts the answer in two cells (the cell with the formula and the one below)...How can I have it so that it only shows the channel ID in the one cell where I entered the formula?

Comment: try: `=INDEX(ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(QUERY(SUBSTITUTE(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(
 IMPORTDATA(A40), 3000, 1), """", ""),
 "where Col1 contains '<meta itemprop=channelId content='"),
 "<meta itemprop=channelId content=|>", "")),1,1)`

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to have this run quicker....When the formula is applied to a list of 10 channels, the cells all say 'Loading' and I get an error saying "There was an error during calculation; some formulas may not calculate successfully."

Comment: Sure, please see here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sCG31I-6KdsyOXBdrpTZtGNYaRN7IeJFvIz2xRqqKX4/edit?usp=sharing

Also, if possible, could you adapt the formula to also pull the Channel Name as well via the link, in the same sort of way that you have pulled the Channel ID?

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get a result with the formula suggested by **[@player0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55106262/17113972)** and so, after a lot of research, racking my brain and spending hours on it, I finally found a viable solution. **[@player0's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55106262/17113972)** formula contains a Regex that doesn't make sense, ie "`<meta itemprop=channelId content=|>`", instead I used REGEXEXTRACT with Regex `"UC[0-9A-Za-z_-]{21 }[AQgw]"`, thus the formula: `=INDEX(ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY(SUBSTITUTE(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IMPORTDATA(A40); 3000; 1);"""";"");"where Col1 contains '<meta itemprop=channelId content='");"UC[0-9A-Za-z_-]{21}[AQgw]"));1;1)`.
[IDs do YouTube](https://qastack.com.br/webapps/54443/format-for-id-of-youtube-video#:%7E:text=ToUInt64(a%2C%200)%3B%0A%7D-,IDs%20do%20YouTube,-ID%20do%20v%C3%ADdeo)